# how to draw coverflow images from the mid of the screen

Tags: iphone

[image]

I want to start the coverflow from mid of the images (i mean from the center to the end))... 
how can I do it.. .is there is any function in the openflow hoo can help me in this issue..

Answer (score 0):

I had read a blog post where you can overlay a transparent uiview and create a normal horizontal scroll view. 
Then overide the function - `(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`  to return your scroll view if clicked on the uiview.

I will try to find the blog post which has sample code to do the same.

However [this link](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/09/how-to-add-coverflow-effect-on-your-iphone-app-openflow/) where it explains how to implement a coverflow in iphone app may help you.